# in R converting grouped row data into columns

Tags: r, reshape2

I have data in the following format -

```
ID EVID ADMIT   DC      DRG  CLIN_C PRIN_DX  
1  AA   1/1/13  2/1/13  ABC  1A234  Y  
1  AA   1/1/13  2/1/13  ABC  1B345  N  
1  AA   1/1/13  2/1/13  ABC  1C234  N  
1  AA   1/1/13  2/1/13  ABC  1234C  N  

1  BB   3/1/13  2/15/13 EEE  C12C3  Y  
1  BB   3/1/13  2/15/13 EEE  1B345  N  
1  BB   3/1/13  2/15/13 EEE  1C234  N  
1  BB   3/1/13  2/15/13 EEE  987D   N  

2  CC   3/1/13  2/15/13 EEE  C12C3  Y  
2  CC   3/1/13  2/15/13 EEE  546X   N  
2  CC   3/1/13  2/15/13 EEE  1C234  N  
2  CC   3/1/13  2/15/13 EEE  1234C  N
```

And I would like the data in the following format:

```
ID EVID ADMIT   DC      DRG  PRIN_DX 1B345  1C234 1234C 987D 546X  
1  AA   1/1/13  2/1/13  ABC  1A234     1      1     1    0    0  
1  BB   3/1/13  2/15/13 EEE  C12C3     1      1     0    1    0  
2  CC   3/1/13  2/15/13 EEE  C12C3     0      1     0    0    1
```

I would like to do this with R, if possible.  I've tried reshape/reshape2, but cannot find an apparent way to deal with the grouped rows - splitting the grouped rows into columns, and aggregating the remaining rows.

Data is a record of several hundred hospital admissions - so reasonable large.

Comment: It's not clear (to me) what is being aggregated and what isn't...it also looks like `PRIN_DX` does not represent the same type of data in long format as it does in wide format. My first thought is that you probably want something like this: `library(reshape2); dcast(ID + EVID + ADMIT + DC + DRG ~ CLIN_C, data = x)`

Comment: The columns ID, EVID, ADMIT, DC, DRG should all be aggregated - this data is the same for a given admission.   The CLINC_C are clinical codes, which identify all the diagnoses assigned during an admission - 1 to 20 can be assigned.   The PRIN_DX identifies the principle diagnosis during an admit.   I would like to convert CLIN_C into seperate columns per admit event, but identify the principle diagnosis if possible.  Would be happy with just the aggregating and rows to columns

Answer (score 5):

Try this assuming `DF` is the input data frame:

```
library(reshape2)

FUN <- function(i) with(DF[i, ], CLIN_C[PRIN_DX == "Y"])
DF$PRIN_DX <- ave(1:nrow(DF), DF$ID, DF$EVID, FUN = FUN)

dcast(DF, ... ~ CLIN_C, fun = length, value.var = 1)
```

which gives:

```
  ID EVID  ADMIT      DC DRG PRIN_DX 1234C 1A234 1B345 1C234 546X 987D C12C3
1  1   AA 1/1/13  2/1/13 ABC   1A234     1     1     1     1    0    0     0
2  1   BB 3/1/13 2/15/13 EEE   C12C3     0     0     1     1    0    1     1
3  2   CC 3/1/13 2/15/13 EEE   C12C3     1     0     0     1    1    0     1
```

UPDATE: simplification

Answer (score 1):

And yet another way using plyr and model.matrix to coerce the factor to dummy variables.  I simplified the data and assumed that there was always a PRIN_DX.

```
df <- data.frame(ID=c(1,1,2,2,3,3), EVID=c(0,0,1,1,3,3), CLIN_C = c('A1','B1','C1','D1','C1','D2'), PRIN_DX=c('Y','N','Y','N','Y','N'))
df$CLIN_C <- factor(df$CLIN_C)

agg_fun <- function(x) {
  temp1 <- x$CLIN[which(x$PRIN_DX=='Y')[1]]
  temp2 <- apply(model.matrix(~x$CLIN_C-1), 2, sum)
  out <- data.frame(temp1, t(temp2))
  names(out) <- c('PRIN_DX', levels(x$CLIN_C))  
  return(out)
}

library(plyr)
ddply(df, .(ID, EVID), agg_fun)
```

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that in the original question, the principle diagnoses (PRIN_DX) are not included as columns in the desired output dataset. So here is an option using plyr and reshape2 to get that result.

```
require(reshape2)
require(plyr)

# Make a variable specifically for the principle diagnosis
df2 = ddply(df, .(ID, EVID, ADMIT, DC, DRG), transform, PRIN_DX2 = CLIN_C[PRIN_DX == "Y"] )
# Pull out the non-principle diagnoses
df2$CLIN_C = ifelse(df2$PRIN_DX == "N", as.character(df2$CLIN_C), NA)

# Make the order of CLIN_C match the order of appearance
df2$CLIN_C = factor(df2$CLIN_C, levels = unique(df2$CLIN_C) )

dcast(na.omit(df2), ID + EVID + ADMIT + DC + DRG + PRIN_DX2 ~ CLIN_C, fun = length)
```

Which gives:

```
  ID EVID  ADMIT      DC DRG PRIN_DX2 1B345 1C234 1234C 987D 546X
1  1   AA 1/1/13  2/1/13 ABC    1A234     1     1     1    0    0
2  1   BB 3/1/13 2/15/13 EEE    C12C3     1     1     0    1    0
3  2   CC 3/1/13 2/15/13 EEE    C12C3     0     1     1    0    1
```